# Unable to route despite having router.get

Tags: html, node.js

Although I have route to the correct page properly, it still show me cannot Get / error. Because my first router get (in agent.js) summons a table before rendering the table so I am not sure how to approach this issue. This is the attempt I have tried below but I get a cannot GET /function%20router(req,%20res,%20next)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20router.handle(req,%20res,%20next);%0A%20%20%7D.

If I try rendering the agent page in route.js, the table will cause an error because the page is rendered before obtaining data from database and render again at the end.

app.js

```
const routesRouter = require("./routes/routes");
const agentRouter = require("./routes/agent");

app.use("/", routesRouter);
app.use("/agent", agentRouter);
```

route.js

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const agentRoute = require("./agent");

router.get("/", async function (req, res) {
  res.render("login.ejs");
});

router.post("/login", async function (req, res) {
  const { username, password } = req.body;

  if (username == 1 && password == 1) {
    res.redirect("/agent");
} 

  else {
    return res.status(401).json({
      message: "Auth fail",
    });
  }

router.get("/agent", async function (req, res) {
  res.redirect(agentRoute);
});

});
```

agent.js

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const mysql = require("mysql");
const db = require("../server");

function getConnection() {
    return mysql.createConnection({
      host: "localhost",
      user: "root",
      password: "",
      database: "nodejs_login",
    });
  }

  router.get("/agent", function (req, res, next) {
    const sql = "SELECT * FROM policy1 WHERE policyAgent = 'Ron'";
    db.query(sql, function (err, data, fields) {
      console.log(data);
      if (err) throw err;
      res.render("agenthome", { title: "Policy List", policyData: data });
    });
  });
  
  module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your **agent.js**, you're still getting **'/agent'** which will result in **http://localhost:3000/agent/agent**

```
router.get("/agent", function (req, res, next) {
    const sql = "SELECT * FROM policy1 WHERE policyAgent = 'Ron'";
    ....
});
```

So change the **router.get("/agent")** to **router.get("/")**  in the **agent.js** file

Answer (score 1):

You're calling redirect function to a router which definitely doesn't work. you've imported and called app.use function to agentRouter in your app.js which should be enough

```
// REMOVE this code from app.js
router.get("/agent", async function (req, res) {    
  res.redirect(agentRoute);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Point 1: change route.js to routes.js

Point 2: i suppose you have used

```
module.exports = router;
```

in route.js